# Unity on a non-widescreen monitor

Tags: unity

Since the launchpad in Unity (or what the bar on the left is called) can't be moved into another position, I wanted to ask you guys how use-able Unity is on a monitor with a maximum screen resolution of 1280x1024. Due to the fact that it's designed for widescreen monitors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't affected by that since the launcher is hidden. However, on a narrow screen (screen is tilted, so it becomes 1080x1920) it becomes needlessly long, just as it would be if it were flat in a wide screen setup.

But there are many other reasons to use Unity in any case. The keyboard support is awesome, for instance. So the answer to your question is that Unity is very useful on any screen that is at least 800x800. Smaller than that would be more difficult, I think, but that has more to do with Gnome than Unity.

You can add other panels and stuff if you like to, by the way. For instance, if you want a taskbar like Gnome 2 and Windows XP, then you can install http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xfce4-panel. Afterwards, press alt+f2 and run `xfce4-panel` to start it. Obviously, if you wanted to use it, then you'd add it to startup applications. The point is that you can combine Unity with other things, like awn or ...